# find key by one of values in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I need find the key by one of the values. However, it get "[]" based on my search codes. Python json file and codes as below.

```
<type 'dict'>

{'university of washington': ['university of washington', 'u dub'], 'brown university': ['brown university', 'brown'], 'university of bath': ['university of bath'], 'deakin university': ['deakin university', 'deakin']}

import json
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import MutableMapping

def get_university_fullnames_dict(one_univ):
        with open('/data.json', 'r') as JSON:
            dic = json.load(JSON)
            my_dict = literal_eval(dic)
            #print type(my_dict)
            #print my_dict
        keys_have_value = [k for k,v in my_dict.items() if v == one_univ]
        return keys_have_value

# result is none, not "deakin university"
get_university_fullnames_dict('deakin')
```

Expected result should be "deakin university".

Comment: If you have to do dictionary lookups from values to key, then you should revise / convert your data structure. Dictionaries are made for key to value lookups.

Comment: @KlausD., I believe this is one of those cases where a reverse lookup on dictionary doesn't harm the very need of them as the keys can't be lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a membership check, not an equality:

```
[k for k, v in d.items() if 'deakin' in v]
```

Your function becomes:

```
def get_university_fullnames_dict(one_univ):
    # .... other codes come here
    return [k for k, v in my_dict.items() if one_univ in v]
```

Comment: Thanks, it should be [k for k, v in d.items() if one_uni in v]. It works